# Proving that successor of a number is not zero

Tags: peano-axioms, formal-proofs

I am stuck proving the simple claim that $Sx \neq 0$ in say Peano Arithmetic (the [first order theory of arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic)) or Robinson Arithmetic or Presburger Arithmetic.
I see that this is sometimes added as an axiom, but it seems not necessary (i.e. derivable)?

Assume we have quantifier-free induction (or at least the axiom that every number is either 0 or a successor).

I have already tried using induction along $A[x] := Sx = 0$, but the induction hypothesis $Sx \neq 0$ doesn't help me with $SSx \neq 0$.

**NB.** I am familiar with a system called PRA where in addition to the usual axioms of robinson arithmetic, we have quantifier free induction and function symbols of all primitive recursive functions plus their defining equations.

That means that

$isz(0) = 0$

$isz(Sx) = S0$

is an axiom of PRA. Here I can easily derive a contradiction if I assume $Sx = 0$:

$S0 = isz(Sx) = isz(0) = 0$, contradicts the axiom $S0 \neq 0$.

Maybe I can do something similar with +, which I have in the theories mentioned above, but I had no success so far.

Comment: If you do not prohibit $Sx=0$, how do you know you do not have the zero ring with $S0=0$?

Comment: $S0 \neq 0$ is an axiom I have, but how does that give me $\forall x. Sx \neq 0$?

Comment: It doesn't.  There are other rings with $Sx=0$ for some $x$.

Comment: I am pretty confident that I should be able to derive that in peano arithmetic, otherwise we would be in trouble. With a set-theoretic/ordinal like approach to defining numbers where 0 is the empty set and other numbers contain the smaller ones it is easy to show this (c.f. e.g. http://tavernini.com/arc/foundations04.pdf section 4-3).

Answer (score 2):

$\forall x \in N :S(x)\ne 0$ (or some equivalent) is always given as one of Peano's axioms.

If instead, you had simply $S(0)\ne 0$ as you suggest, then your axioms would be satisfied by having $N=\{0,1\}, 0\ne 1, S(0)=1$ and $S(1)=0$. In any case, you would not be able to prove $\forall x \in N :S(x)\ne 0$ since it would not be strictly required by your axioms.